# Can CallKit (Call Directory Extension) identify and block cellular calls

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, callkit

Firstly I am new to iOS development and I have extensively gone over the little documentation and tutorials there are of Apples CallKit framework, but I cannot figure out if this framework can actually block cellular calls or just VoIP calls?

The question is as simple as that, I need to know if CallKit can be used to block cellular calls, when I have predefined a list of telemarketers that use their mobile phones to call people in my country. I am just wondering if someone can give me a clear cut answer and then I could move on with my life, without having to waste more time, trying to get the CallKit to recognize incoming cellular calls.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can block incoming cellular calls.

Comment: Although I could mark the question as answered, if youd leave an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can block incoming calls using a CallKit extension